# For concave functions $f(y) \le f(x) + f'(x)(y − x), ∀x, y$ but....

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

For concave functions $f(y) \le f(x) + f'(x)(y − x), ∀x, y$, but this can also be written as $f'(x) \ge (f(y)-f(x))/(y-x) ∀x, y$, but isn't  this only applicable when $y \ge x$ and not when $x \le y$. [This is the graph for what i am asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xguxf.jpg):

[image]

Please can someone clear this out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this is only applicable in the case you mention. If $y-x$ is negative (which it is if $y<x$), you have to flip the $\leq$-sign when dividing by $y-x$.

So in this case you get $f'(x)\leq\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.